# Flutter: Pop from AlertBuilder and then show SnackBar

Tags: flutter, popup, navigator, snackbar

I am new in Flutter as well as App Development, What I want to achieve is Show SnackBar after poping from alertbuilder.
I think following code will be useful for understanding my intentions

```
onSubmitted: (value) async {
                            try {
                              await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                  .sendPasswordResetEmail(
                                      email: _loginEmail);
                            } catch (e) {
                              SnackBar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                                content: Text(e.toString()),
                                duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                              );
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            }
                            SnackBar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                              content: Text('Email sent with a link!'),
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                            );
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it'll solve your problem

1, You should await your `showDialog` at your `onpressed` event like this

```
var result = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
       title: Text("your title")
       content: Text("your content")
       actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, 'success'); // here you can make a callback
          },
          child: Text('Okay')),]
    );
  },
);
```

2, so you can write

```
if(result=="success"){}
```

3, Then, show your `SnackBar` after that.
Before showing `SnackBar` you have to add your snackbar prop like I write below

```
final snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text('Your context message'));
```

and then you can show the `snackbar` with your context like this

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
```